# install4j: compilation failed. Reason: java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset

Tags: install4j

I have an install4j project that is compilation and building absolutely fine on windows.  When I try this on linux however I receive the error stated in the title.  I've turned verbose mode on but I don't receive anything more helpful than that.  As the code is obfuscated I can't even make a guess about what might be wrong.

Is there some other kind of logging I can add to get more information about what might be going wrong during compilation?

```
 [exec]   Compiling launchers:
 [exec] com.A.B.E: java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
 [exec]     at com.A.B.D.R(ejt:2613)
 [exec]     at com.install4j.B.E.F.C(ejt:1892)
 [exec]     at com.install4j.B.E.B.b(ejt:3208)
 [exec]     at com.install4j.B.F.i(ejt:1193)
 [exec]     at com.install4j.B.F.J(ejt:2499)
 [exec]     at com.install4j.B.A.m(ejt:3411)
 [exec]     at com.install4j.B.B.?(ejt:311)
 [exec]     at com.install4j.B.B.?(ejt:1515)
 [exec]     at com.install4j.B.B.H(ejt:2287)
 [exec]     at com.install4j.Install4JApplication.?(ejt:436)
 [exec]     at com.A.M.?(ejt:2208)
 [exec]     at com.install4j.Install4JApplication.main(ejt:1879)
 [exec]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [exec]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 [exec]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [exec]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 [exec]     at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
 [exec] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
 [exec]     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(Native Method)
 [exec]     at com.A.B.A.H.A(ejt:1114)
 [exec]     at com.A.B.A.H.S(ejt:179)
 [exec]     at com.A.B.A.H.K(ejt:2639)
 [exec]     at com.A.B.A.H.<init>(ejt:2868)
 [exec]     at com.A.B.D.e(ejt:3063)
 [exec]     at com.A.B.D.R(ejt:3485)
 [exec]     ... 17 more
 [exec] install4j: compilation failed. Reason: java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
```

Comment: What version of install4j do you use?

Comment: Currently using 5.0.11, was going to try upgrading to latest version but the same project is working fine on windows.  Shame there isn't more debug I could access.

Comment: An upgrade to the latest version (5.1.3) that's just been released fixed this.